# Missing message when using child_process.send in CoffeeScript

Tags: node.js, process, coffeescript

I've just started with coffeescript, and I like it, but I've run into a frustrating problem. When I reproduce the basic version of sending and receiving messages between a process and a forked child process in javascript I get the expected result. So far, all good.

----------- app2.js -----------------------------

```
var child = require('child_process');
var forked = child.fork("./child2.js");

forked.on('message', function (msg) {
    console.log("parent recieved ", msg);
});

forked.send({hello:'world'});
```

---------- child2.js --------------------------------

```
process.on('message', function(m) {
    console.log("child received ", m);
});

process.send({foo:'bar'});
```

-------------- output of node app2.js -----

```
child received  { hello: 'world' }
parent recieved  { foo: 'bar' }
```

Yet when I reproduce the example in coffeescript, I only get the parent receiving the message from the child process; the child process does not, apparently, receive the message from the parent.

-----------app.coffee ----------------------------

```
cp = require('child_process')
n = cp.fork("./child.coffee")

n.on 'message', (m) =>
    console.log 'PARENT recieved', m

n.send {foo:'hello from the parent process'}
```

---------- child.coffee ---------------------------

```
process.on 'message', (m) =>
    console.log 'CHILD received ', m

console.log "Child process running"

process.send {bar:'hello from the child process'}
```

-------------------- output of coffee app.coffee ----

```
Child process running
PARENT recieved { bar: 'hello from the child process' }
```

Looking at the compiled javascript, I see (as expected) that the result of compiling the coffeescript is essentially the same as the original javascript code, just wrapped in a function with a call on this. The problem must be one of scope, but I cannot see how to resovlve it. No doubt it will be trivial for the Gurus, and I'm at the end of my tether with it, so I thought I'd ask in case someone is kind enough to show me the way.

Dr Darryn Reid.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately this isn't as simple as a scoping issue. The problem is your fork command, which in the JS case will start a new `node` process, and in the CoffeeScript case will start a new `coffee` process.

I can't say for sure without lots of time hunting, but the issue is a difference in their startup/compilation time, or something related to that.

```
// Changing this line
n.send {foo:'hello from the parent process'}

// to this works for me
setTimeout (-> n.send {foo:'hello from the parent process'}), 300
```

I think the simplest solution for you would be to not send any messages to the child until you've gotten some initial `'ready'` event from the child process. So you can have your `child.coffee` send some initial message that will tell the parent process that it has finally compiled and loaded fully.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I appreciate it. I guess it amounts to "think asynchronously"; I think the documentation on node.js should really change to make it more robust. It isn't much of a change, just having the parent process send its message only after receiving the message from the child. Thanks again.